# Найти минимальное нечётное число из случайного набора чисел

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Необходимо найти минимальное нечётное число из случайного набора чисел (сгенерировать случайный набор чисел)

```
import random
numbers = []
counter = 0
while counter < 10:
    numbers.append(random.randint(1, 100))
    counter += 1
    min_number = 100000000000000000000
    for number in numbers:
        if number < min_number:
            min_number = number
            print(numbers)
            print(min_number)
            print(sorted(numbers)[1])
```

Comment: А в чём вопрос?

Comment: Ну как, получилось найти?

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое решение

```
import random

nums = list(random.randint(0,100000) for i in range(100))
min_num = []
for item in nums:
    if item % 2 != 0:
        min_num.append(item)
print(min(min_num))
```

В коде генерируются 100 случайных чисел в диапазоне от 0 до 100000

Comment: `min(r for r in (random.randint(0,100000) for _ in range(100)) if r % 2 != 0)` - проще будет.

Comment: это просто реализация в 1 строку. Где простота? Как раз таки однострочный код сложнее понять

Comment: Нет лишнего списка `nums`, нет лишнего списка `min_num`. Чем меньше деталей, тем проще.

Comment: будучи новичком этот код сложнее к пониманию. В чем прикол писать более сложный код?)

Comment: Я написал понятный и читабельный код, в вашем варианте однострочник

Comment: В таком случае я могу написать еще более удобный код ```print(min(filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(100)])))```

Comment: `[...]` -> `(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 # 2. Найти максимальное чётное чило из случайного набора чисел(Сгенерировать 
 случайный набор чисел)
 import random
numbers = []
counter = 0
while counter < 100:
    numbers.append(random.randint(1, 1000))
    counter += 1
min_number = 99999999999999999999999999999
for number in numbers:
    if number < min_number:
        min_number = number
print(numbers)
print(min_number)
print(sorted(numbers)[0])
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Нет проверки на чётность/нечётность числа.  Переменная `counter` не нужна, проще было обычный цикл `for i in range(1000)` использовать